# Extract and sum multiple numbers from a Cell, including numbers with decimals

Tags: microsoft-excel

I was wondering if there was a formula to be able to look at the information in a cell that contains both text and numbers (sometimes with decimals), and extract and provide a sum of the numbers. Example below:

**Initial text narrative (2.1); following text narrative (3.2); additional text narrative (3.1); final text narrative (1.9).**

The sum of the numbers above should total 10.30. Please let me know if such a formula exists.

Thank You,

Comment: Yes, it does exist.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a combination of FIND, LEFT, LEN and NUMBERVALUE to get to your result.

A1 put your string here

A2 "=FIND("(";A1;2)" gives you the position of the first open bracket

A3 "=RIGHT(A1;LEN(A1)-A2)" gives you the string, but starts with the first number

A4 "=LEFT(A3;3)" gives you your first number as text

A5 "=NUMBERVALUE(A4;".")" gives you your first number

Now repeat the above steps on A3 to get the second number, and so on, until you have all numbers, which you can then sum.

How well this works depends on how well your data is structured.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Office 2010 or later:

```
=SUM(FILTERXML("<z>"& SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"(","<y>"),")","</y>")&"</z>","//y"))
```

Depending on your version one may need to confirm the formula with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Comment: Thank You so much